# Abuse suid program

Tags: linux, sudoers, setuid

I have some questions about setuid binary.
I know it exists some dangerous program (if you permit to use this program with sudo, it is possible to escape from the program and get a root shell) like ftp, gdb or find.
For example, if i can make a sudo ftp with root rights, i can then enter !/bin/bash and get a root shell.

So i was thinking it was the same problem for this binary if they've got the suid bit. So i tried on my computer and here is the problem.
I put suid right on /usr/bin/netkit-ftp (/usr/bin/ftp is a symbloic link to /usr/bin/netkit-ftp).
Here is the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/netkit-ftp`

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 96968 déc.   6  2016 /usr/bin/netkit-ftp
```

Then i tried to use ftp and enter !whoami. And the result is not root (it'm my current username).

I dont understand why ? If the binary /usr/bin/netkit-ftp got suid bit, it is supposed to be execute with root permission, no ? (so why my whoami isn't returning me root ?)

Cordially :)

Comment: (1) Make sure you run the right executable (your `$PATH` may find another `ftp` before the one in `/usr/bin`). (2) In general programs running with SUID root can [fallback to the real user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74538/108618).

Answer (score 1):

Each process has at least two UID sets (usually three or more). One of them is the "real" UID, which determines what user *owns* the process. The other is the "effective" UID, which determines the *permissions* that the process has. You can find the Linux description in [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

When a 'setuid' program starts, only its "effective" UID is changed, so that it has the new privileges but still knows *who* launched it. (That's how sudo knows who you are, even though it's setuid.)

Example:

```
$ sudo cp /bin/id /bin/test-id
$ sudo chmod u+s,g+s /bin/test-id

$ ls -la /bin/test-id
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 42K Jan  4 11:59 /bin/test-id*

$ /bin/test-id
uid=1000(grawity) gid=1000(grawity) euid=0(root) egid=0(root) groups=1000(grawity),3(sys),4(adm),10(wheel),100(users)
```

A freshly started program like this will already have root privileges. For example, if you give the setuid bit to `cat` or `less`, then any user will be able to read root-only files.

Programs can change this state in two directions: they can change both UIDs to EUID (fully "becoming root"), *or* they can change both to the real UID (dropping privileges and returning to your "normal" user). I think *sudo* does the former, but you'll also often see many programs doing the latter.

Note that the *bash* shell also does the latter: if you try to give the setuid bit to `/bin/bash`, it will relinquish its setuid privileges on startup, *unless* it was started with the `-p` (--privileged) option. You can see this in bash's [flags.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/flags.c#n152) and [shell.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n502).

This is important because when you use `!` in *ftp*, the provided command isn't executed directly; it's actually run through a shell, and what applies to the shell also applies to !-commands. That is, the *sh* process started by *ftp* will actually inherit the setuid state (euid=0) exactly as you expect, but will relinquish it before running the provided command.

*(This means that entering `!/bin/bash` actually runs *two* shell processes: the first one has the right euid but drops privileges before starting the second one.)*

You can test (and bypass) this by telling *ftp* to use something else as the initial shell:

```
$ ls -l /bin/id /bin/test-ftp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  42K Aug 19 12:54 /bin/id*
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 137K Jan  4 12:08 /bin/test-ftp*

$ SHELL=/bin/id /bin/test-ftp
ftp> !
uid=1000(grawity) gid=1000(grawity) euid=0(root) egid=0(root) groups=0(root),3(sys),4(adm),10(wheel),100(users)
ftp>
```

(Note: Not all programs look at $SHELL; some always use /bin/sh, or no shell at all.)

Comment: Thx for this explanation ! :)